# upgrade rancher service from .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, rancher

I have created a stack which contains one container (service) on rancher.

This container has been created from an image which is hosted on a gitlab-ci project registry.

I want to force rancher to download a new version of this image and upgrade container.

I want to do this from a .gitlab-ci.yml script.

Here is an extract of my .gitlab-ci.yml:

(Please note i have set RANCHER_ACCESS_KEY, RANCHER_SECRET_KEY, RANCHER_URL secrets variables in gitlab web interface)

```
deploiement:
  stage: deploiement
  tags: [dockerrunnertag]
  image: tagip/rancher-cli
  script:
    - rancher --debug up -d --stack "mystack"
    - rancher --debug up -d --force-upgrade --pull --stack "mystack" --confirm-upgrade app
```

My problem is that gitlab is automaticly copy my source code into this tagip/rancher-cli container.
This container is temporary. I just want to run it in order to fire an action on rancher server.

How can i disable this fetching source code feature ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Simply add the GIT_STRATEGY variable to your deployment job.

```
variables:
   GIT_STRATEGY: none
```

Reference: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21337